Свой VPN на golang
Решил сделать свой VPN на golang. В принципе основную часть сделал:

Программа создаёт виртуальный интерфейс TUN
Подключается к VPN серверу по UDP
И передает данные из TUN на сервер, а с сервера в TUN

На сервере примерно тот же самый сценарий. Как я понял, это уже является VPN (только без шифрования, но это я добавлю). Хотелось бы дать клиенту доступ в интернет, то есть что бы на сервере IP пакеты отправлялись дальше в сеть и с сети клиенту. Это я и не понимаю, как сделать.
Всё делаю под Windows.

Может проще взять что-то готовое и посмотреть как там делаются дела?

Сервер на виндовс?

Да. Вообще хочу в принципе понять, как это сделать. Буду благодарен, если подскажите решение для другой ОС.

В идеале, конечно, сделать кроссплатформенное решение.
